# A strange message from space?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking, knowledge, acrostic

I was listening to AM radio (frequency 1480) the other day and an odd message came through in what seemed like an infinite loop.

> Drop 5.
>
> Echo 0.
>
> Negate 0.
>
> Split 4.
>
> Enter 1.

A few hours later, my friend stopped by in disbelief of this message; I turned it back to the radio station and the message had changed and repeated itself every second.

> Add
>
> S

I can't seem to figure it out; maybe you can help?

---

### Hints

I listen to that station once a day to listen for new messages; and each time it seems a new message is playing. Maybe these are clues?

> Take all.
>  No light.
>  What's my name?
>  Supermassive!
>  There exists, a list of extraordinary objects.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer.

I think the message may be about:

> A **black hole**.

Firstly...

> The acrostic of your puzzle's first clue spell **DENSE**. Black holes are believed to have a region of infinite density.

Also...

> Your subsequent hints: "Take all" may refer to the fact that black holes draw everything into them, and "no light" exists in a black hole.

Secondly...

> I believe the lines are telling us to modify the AM radio frequency 1480 to either form a message or possible "spell out" a word. I just can't quite figure it out.

My working so far:

> - If you "drop 5" from 1480 you get **1475**
>   - If "echo 0" means add a 0 on the end you get **14750** but I'm not sure that is what it means.
>   - If "negate 0" means make the 0 a 'negative' you get **1475-0** but again I'm not sure that is what it means.
>   - If you "split" the number at the number 4 you get **1 475-0**
>   - If you "Enter 1" into the gap you just made you get **11475-0**
>
>   If you look at that number *backwards* the last 3 digits "411" look rather like the word "**ALL**", and the first hint is "**TAKE ALL**". Also the remaining digits 7, 5 and 0 all look a bit like alpha characters - L (or possibly T?), S and O; and we are also asked in the final clue to "Add S" which suggests that we are meant to view the numbers as alpha-characters.

Comment: ROT13(V jbhyq fnl 7 ybbxf zber yvxr n G guna na Y. Nyfb, lbh sbetbg gb nqq na F, gubhtu V'z abg fher jurer vg jbhyq tb.)

Comment: So you're diving down a rabbit hole; the acrostic is simply *DENSE*; the `knowledge` tag is included for a reason. You are correct in using the frequency; but you're going to need to utilize the `lateral-thinking` with its relationship to that message. I wouldn't say all of the instructions are correct. ;)

Comment: You are correct on what the message is about, and that you need to modify the frequency. Added a hint.

Answer (score 5):

Following Astralbee's conclusions:

> Starting with the "negate 0", we simply drop it completely. That leaves us with the following number at completion: **11475** 
> If we straight up convert that to possible letters, we have two options: **11 4 7 5** and **1 14 7 5** 
> Using basic numerical substitution, the former gives us **K D G E** and the latter gives us **A N G E** 
> Now we add "S", which gives us **K D G E S** and **A N G E S**. While I can't do anything with the former, the latter can be rearranged to spell **AGNES**

Answer (score 1):

**Partial Answer**

Based off Astralbee's and Larry Alton Garrett's logic, I believe you may be referring to

> a quasar

---

Pivoting off of the prior two answers, my logic is as follows:

> Taking the AM frequency **1480** as a raw number, we follow the instructions as below:
>  "DROP 5" = Subtract five: 1475
>  "ECHO 0" = Append a zero at the end: 14750
>  "NEGATE 0" = **Invert the zero** (as if it were a bit): 14751
>  "SPLIT 4" = Split at the number four: 1_4751 *or* 14_751
>  "ENTER 1" = Place a one in the gap: 114751 *or* 141751

Taking the sequence of numbers to stand for letters, there could be several groupings (I only list the ones that felt the most pertinent; there's bound to be several others that may be more revealing):

> 1. 114751 = 11 4 7 5 1  =  K D G E A 
>  *or* 2. 1 14 7 5 1  =  **A N G E A** 
>  3. 141751 = 14 17 5 1   =  N Q E A 
>  *or* 4. 14 1 7 5 1  =  N A G E A 
>  
>  (Interesting that #2 and #4 are anagrams...)

Taking one of these sequences, we notice the word

> AGN, which stands for "active galactic nucleus," an attribute to quasars

…and from your hints, we can make some reasonable assumptions, since

> quasars are quite D-E-N-S-E, supermassive, and certainly "extraordinary" interstellar objects! Furthermore, you mention that this was from a *radio* frequency; quasars can be classified as radio-quiet or radio-loud, which might explain why it's a "strange message from space".

---

The parts where I'm unsure:

> - I think you are asking for a specific type of quasar (or a named one, at least), given the extra letters "EA"; adding "S" (as per the second set of instructions) doesn't *seem* to clarify anything alphabetically or by value.
>  - Not sure if the fact it is an AM frequency (and not a FM frequency) has any difference; perhaps these are extra letters?
>  - Your hint, "No light", seems to contradict the idea that this is a quasar, since quasars can emit quite a lot of light (EM radiation). 
>  - I'm also making an assumption on which sequence is a viable one, given I'm not quite sure of all the possible sequences available.